# Thread creation in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Is it possible to create a thread and control threads in windows 8.1 store apps.. If so how is it done?

The documentation mentions that Thread class is supported for w8.1 in the System.Threading namespace but it doesn't appear when creating w8.1 store apps in VS2013.

Also there was a Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in windows 8. Is there an equivalent to this on w8.1?

I have read about Tasks but am still unclear as to how it relates to threading.

Answer (score 2):

A `Task` is essentially a wrapper for a delegate which is scheduled to do some work on a particular `TaskScheduler`. The `TaskScheduler` scheduler the work on one or more threads.

`TaskScheduler.Default` executes tasks on a thread pool and that's the one you use most often if you want something to execute in the background. You can also use a scheduler `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSyncrhonizationContext()` which will run the task on the current `SynchroniztionContext`. In the case of a GUI app this is the UI thread.

In .NET 4.5 You can run tasks on the thread pool by simply calling `Task.Run` and passing in an `Action`.

Also `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` is supported on Windows 8.1 according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206(v=vs.110).aspx).